# safe publication using method confinement in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider a snippet from a class :

```
    // tail call to show
void showNextPoint(){
    Point p = new Point();
    p.x = 10;
    p.y = 12;
    show(p);
}

// multiple calls to show
void showPoints(){
    Point p = new Point();
    p.x = 10;   p.y = 12;
    show(p);
    p.x = 20;   p.y = 22;
    show(p);
    p.x = 30;   p.y = 32;
    show(p);
}

void show(Point p){
    // use p in some way
    // can p's state be changed safely ?
            // can a new thread be started to work with p safely ?      
}
```

In a multithreaded use-case , can the object `p` be considered as published safely from the `showPoints()` or `showNextPoint()` ? What conditions must hold true in `show()` for this ?

If `show(Point p)` is guaranteed  1) not to start a new thread and 2) not to change p's state   , can the `showPoints()` method be considered as safely publishing `p` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show()` method gets a reference to a `Point p`.  If the caller afterwards makes a change to `p`, it is making a change to the *same* Object.  If `show()` changes `p` in any way then it is updating the same `p` object that the caller is using.  If a thread is forked that has this `p` then you have a race condition as to which update to `p` is performed in which order.

```
Point p = new Point(1, 2);
show(p);
// p.x == 100 here

void show(Point p) {
   p.x = 100;
}
```

You asked:

```
void show(Point p){
    // use p in some way
    // can p's state be changed safely ?
    // can a new thread be started to work with p safely ?      
}
```

It cannot be changed safely without affecting the caller's object, no.  A new thread also cannot make changes to `p` without it affecting the caller's object when memory synchronization happens.

> In a multithreaded use-case , can the object p be considered as published safely from the `showPoints()` or `showNextPoint()` ? What conditions must hold true in show() for this ?

It all depends on how you've written the code -- what the contracts are.  If a method makes changes to an object then it should be documented.  If the caller does not wish this then either you should pass in a copy of a `Point` object that the method could "own" or the method itself should copy `Point` itself.

The complications around synchronizing changes to object is one of the reasons why many Java objects are immutable.  You may consider doing this to `Point`.  Make it so the `x` and `y` values cannot be changed which means that the `show` method and any threads it spawn can safely use the argument without worrying about changed being made to it from the caller.

**Edit:**

> If show(Point p) is guaranteed 1) not to start a new thread and 2) not to change p's state , can the showPoints() method be considered as safely publishing p ?

@JohnVint had some better points about this but I thought I'd add my thoughts.  I'm not sure what you are asking here and I'm not sure what you think "safely publishing" implies.  The devil is in the details.  If `show()` doesn't start a new thread then yes, the code you have posted will work and it's okay to use the same mutable `Point` object.

Any method that takes an object argument but does not change the object in any way can say that it is "safely using" (I guess) the object.  Since `showPoints()` constructed the object and has the only reference to it then that is certainly safe as well.  It's when `p` gets modified and there is another thread involved that everything changes.

Comment: I didn't read his `showPoints()` clear enough in which wouldn't apply as much to my answer.  I wanted to reword my comment.  Basically the only way it would be safely published is if a thread wasnt created before any of the Points were created.  Otherwise your answer pretty much addresses it all

Comment: @JohnVint  Yokay.  I still think you should make it an answer.  I often say something like "@Jim's answer was good but I'd like to add..." sort of answers.  I think good for posterity.

Comment: @Gray, can you please comment on the questions I mention towards the end ? My thoughts are on the lines that if as long as no thread is started from within `show()` , the publication as such is safe , even if the object as a whole is running on multiple threads.

Comment: @JohnVint, would be glad to hear your comments/answers.

Comment: @Bhaskar I've edited my answer to address your last question.